# Override bootstrap-table selected row background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery bootstrap-table plugin and I need to change the color of the selected row and restore the original color when I click the next row. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/haideraliarain/e3nk137y/789/ explains how to do this. However, I would like to have the color highlight of my choice instead of the default green. I have tried this using the code below which changes the color but problem is that the color of the selected row changes on next click and not immediately. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/amotha/1yvr1kun/2/
How can I make the change happen on the current click?

html:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table"
       data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/"
       data-click-to-select="true"
       data-single-select="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-visible="false"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

js:

```
    $('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        $('.success').removeClass('success');
        $('.success').css("background-color","#fff");
        $($element).addClass('success');
        $('.success').css("background-color","#00FFFF");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

done [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yvr1kun/4/) change the color that you want in the css part

```
.success td
{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom class in CSS:

```
tr.custom--success td {
  background-color: #000000; /*custom color here add !important if you don't want the hover color*/
}
```

Then your Javascript:

```
$('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $('.custom--success').removeClass('custom--success');
    $($element).addClass('custom--success');
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kguL1ow/1/

This should give you what you need.

If anything is unclear, please ask, then I will explain in a bit more depth why and what is going on.

Comment: The selected row gets highlighted but the original color not restored when another row is clicked.

Comment: Aaah, I was not sure if you wanted the row to stay highlighted or not, editing post now

Answer (score 0):

I have created a css for selected table background color like:

```
<style>
.tblcss{
  background-color: red /* You can use any color of you choice here */
}
</style>
```

and use it:

```
 $('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        $('.success').removeClass('tblcss');
        $($element).addClass('tblcss');
});
```

Check the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/9177/)

Comment: Does'nt work. Did you mean `$('element').removeClass('tblcss');` and not `$('.success').removeClass('tblcss');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yvr1kun/6/)

```
  $('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $($element).siblings().removeClass('success');      
    $($element).addClass('success');

  });
```